# How to change CSS to Vertical Tabs using flexbox in CSS Only

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to see if there is a way to create vertical tabs by changing the CSS only. The solution I am using works great for horizontal tabs and is CSS only. I am trying to see if I can modify the CSS to make it vertical tabs without changing the HTML.

```css
[role=tablist] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
}

[role=tabpanel] {
  order: 9999;
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

label:has(:checked) + [role=tabpanel] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div role="tablist">
    <label>
        Tab 1
        <input name="tablist" type="radio" checked="">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <label role="tab">
        Tab 2
        <input name="tablist" type="radio">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 2 content. Invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
    </div>
    <label role="tab">
        Tab 3
        <input name="tablist" type="radio">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 3 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
    </div>
</div>
```

I just need to know if there is a way to move the tab panels to the top right without using position absolute as I need to retain the height of them. Or if there is some way to do with `flex-grow`, `shrink`, `basis`, etc. for the tabs or using `xxxx-self` on the tabs or tab panels, etc.

Bonus if I can also align the tabs to the right with tab panels on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of interface is most suitable for `grid`:

```css
[role="tablist"] {
  /* 2 columns & 3 rows, with the right part marked as "d" */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a d'
    'b d'
    'c d';
}

label {
  grid-column: 1;
}

[role="tabpanel"] {
  /* Assign any visible panel to the "d" area */
  grid-area: d;
}
```

Try it:

```css
[role="tablist"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a d'
    'b d'
    'c d';
  margin: auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  grid-column: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[role="tabpanel"] {
  display: none;
  grid-area: d;
  padding: 1em;
}

label:has(:checked) + [role="tabpanel"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div role="tablist">
  <label role="tab">
    Tab 1
    <input name="tablist" type="radio" checked>
  </label>
  <div role="tabpanel">
    Tab 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <label role="tab">
    Tab 2
    <input name="tablist" type="radio">
  </label>
  <div role="tabpanel">
    Tab 2 content. Invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
  </div>
  <label role="tab">
    Tab 3
    <input name="tablist" type="radio">
  </label>
  <div role="tabpanel">
    Tab 3 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. See my answer to allow for unknown tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @InSync, Yes it seems css-grid is the way to go, but I need a solution that doesn't require knowing the amount of tabs.

I did find a solution, but does require adding a high number like 9999 to the grid-row and you can't use gap as it will add a lot up space with the high number on grid-row.

```css
[role=tablist] {
  display: grid;
  background: #eee;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
}

[role=tabpanel] {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 9999;
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

label:has(:checked) + [role=tabpanel] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div role="tablist">
    <label>
        Tab 1
        <input name="tablist" type="radio" checked="">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <label role="tab">
        Tab 2
        <input name="tablist" type="radio">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 2 content. Invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
    </div>
    <label role="tab">
        Tab 3
        <input name="tablist" type="radio">
    </label>
    <div role="tabpanel">
        Tab 3 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to change the tabs to the right side then you can just adjust the following:

```css
[role=tablist] {
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}

label {
  grid-column: 2;
}

[role=tabpanel] {
  grid-column: 1;
}
```